# Generic invertibility of a Gramian-like matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

**Motivation:** Consider the cascade arising from connecting the system $\dot{x}_1 = A_1 x_1 + B_1 u_1$ with the system $\dot{x}_2 = A_2 x_2$, $y_2 = C_2 x_2$ according to $u_1 = y_2$, namely:
$\dot{x} = \begin{bmatrix}A_1 &B_1C_2\\0 &A_2\end{bmatrix}x$
where $x =[x_1'\; x_2']'$, $B_1\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, $C_2\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$
and $rank(B_1) = rank(C_2) = m$ (a typical case is m = 1). It is assumed

It is assumed that $(A_1, B_1)$ is reachable and $(A_2, C_2)$ is observable, namely that
$rank (R_1) = n = rank (O_2)$, where $R_1 := \begin{bmatrix} B_1 &A_1B_1 &\cdots &A_1^{n-1}B_1\end{bmatrix}$ and $O_2 := \begin{bmatrix}C_2 \\ C_2A_2 \\ \vdots \\ C_2 A_2^{n-1}\end{bmatrix}$.

By integrating over the interval $[0, T]$, it follows that
$x(T) = \begin{bmatrix}e^{A_1T} & e^{A_1T}\int_0^T e^{-A_1\tau} B_1C_2 e^{A_2\tau}d\tau\\ 0 &e^{A_2T} \end{bmatrix}x(0)$

**Question:** I want to prove that matrix $M=\int_0^T e^{-A_1\tau} B_1C_2 e^{A_2\tau}d\tau$ is invertible for generic choices of $T\neq 0$, $A_1$, $A_2$, $B_1$, $C_2$ (i.e. for all choices of parameters in the relevant domains, excluding a set of measure zero).

**Note:**

- it is well known that for $A_1=A_2'$, $B_1=C_2'$ matrix $M$ is a Gramian matrix which is invertible for all $T\neq 0$ (due to the reachability/observability hypothesis)
- $det(M)$ is an analytic function of the parameters $T$, $A_1$, $A_2$, $B_1$, $C_2$, hence it vanishes on a set of zero measure as a complex function (see  [here](http://books.google.ca/books?id=L0zJmamx5AAC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false), Corollary 10, p.9, which is referred to in this  [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352142/zeros-set-of-analytic-functions-over-complex-plane-with-several-variables/353382#353382)). Does this hold when the domain is restricted to real values?