# Complex Measure Agreeing on Certain Balls

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis

I came across this problem and am lost as to how to solve it.

Let $r>0$ be fixed. Suppose $\mu,
\nu$ are complex Borel measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that for each open ball B of radius $r$, $\mu(B)=\nu(B)$. Then $\mu=\nu$.

I thought this might be an application of $\pi-\lambda$ theorem, but I realized we wouldn't have a $\pi$-system with the collection of open balls $B$ since intersecting such balls might not necessarily be open or have radius $r$ still. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In which context did you come across this claim/exercise? The claim is indeed true, but it seems to me (see below) to be more of a Fourier-analytic theorem than a theorem of measure theory. If you do not know much about the Fourier transform, the following proof will probably be (almost) useless to you :(

By considering $\gamma := \mu - \nu$ it suffices to show $\gamma \equiv 0$ if $\gamma (B_r (x)) = 0$ for all $x \in \Bbb{R}^d$.

Let $f := \chi_{B_r (0)}$ be the indicator function/characteristic function of the ball of radius $r$ around the origin. We consider the **convolution** (cf. also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Convolution_of_measures) of the complex measure $\gamma$ and the function $f$, i.e.

$$
\gamma \ast f (x) = \int f(y-x) \, d\gamma(y) = \gamma(B_r (x)) = 0 \text{ for all x } \in \Bbb{R}^d.
$$

But by the convolution theorem for the Fourier transform, we have

$$
0 \equiv \mathcal{F} ( \gamma \ast f) = \widehat{\gamma} \cdot \widehat{f} \qquad (\dagger)
$$

Since $f$ has compact support, the Paley-Wiener theorem (or an explicit differentiation under the integral) shows that the Fourier transform $\widehat{f}$ extends to an entire function $\Bbb{C}^d \to \Bbb{C}$, which we again denote by $\widehat{f}$. Since $f \not\equiv 0$, we also have $\widehat{f} \not\equiv 0$.

As $\widehat{f}$ is analytic, this implies that the zero-set

$$
\{\xi \in \Bbb{R}^d \mid \widehat{f}(\xi) = 0\}
$$

has empty interior, i.e. $\{\xi \mid\widehat{f}(\xi) \neq 0\}$ is dense in $\Bbb{R}^d$.

Together with the continuity of $\widehat{\gamma}$ and with $(\dagger)$, this yields $\widehat{\gamma} \equiv 0$ and thus $\gamma \equiv 0$, completing the proof.

EDIT: Regarding the zero sets of analytic functions, see e.g. here [Zeros set of analytic functions over complex plane with several variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352142/zeros-set-of-analytic-functions-over-complex-plane-with-several-variables). But this does not really cover our case, since we are considering a real analytic function. Let us assume that we already know that real-analytic functions in one variable have only isolated zero sets. (This follows easily by considering the power series $\sum a_n x^n$ and letting $n$ minimal with $a_n\neq0$, ...).

For the multidimensional case, assume $f\equiv 0$ on some open ball $B_r (x_0)$. Let $x\in \Bbb{R}^d$ be arbitrary and consider the analytic(!) single variable function

$$
t \mapsto f((1-t)x_0 + txt)
$$

This function vanishes on an open neighborhood neighborhood of $0$, so that the 1-dimensional case implies that it vanishes identically. Hence, $f$ vanishes identically.

EDIT 2: It should also be observed that the claim is **not** true for measures of infinite (but still locally finite) measures: Consider for example

$$
d\mu(x)= (1+\cos(\pi x))\,dx
$$
on $\Bbb{R}$ with $r=1$. What happens here is that $\hat{\gamma}$ is not a continuous function anymore, but a finite sum of diracs. Thus, the argument above fails, since $\hat{f}$ has some (isolated) zeros.

Comment: Thanks! Most of the proof makes sense. Is it a basic fact that zero-sets of analytic functions have empty interior?

Comment: @user196559: Good question, I edited my answer. Would you mind if I add the "Fourier analysis" tag to your question?

Comment: Not at all! Thanks!

Comment: @PhoemueX could you point a book where this proof is shown?

Comment: @Exodd: What proof do you mean precisely? Are you referring to the whole proof that I give above (i.e., that two finite measures that agree on all $B_r (x), x \in \Bbb{R}^d$ are equal), or just to the proof concerning the zero-sets of analytic functions? For the first one, I am not aware of any book where this is shown. When I came up with the answer, I was actually surprised that this holds. For the second one, you can consider any book on "several complex variables" and look for the "identity theorem". See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Several_complex_variables#Holomorphic_functions

Comment: @PhoemueX I meant the proof for the measures agreeing on balls