# zero set of complex analytic functions has zero measure

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Based on [the answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352142/zeros-set-of-analytic-functions-over-complex-plane-with-several-variables), the following result is clear:

``Given a complex analytic function $f(x)$ with $x$ is in an open connected set $D  \subseteq 
  \mathbb{C}^n$, the zero set $$F = \{x \in D | f(x) = 0\}$$ has $2n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure zero"

Now consider a slightly different situation:

A complex analytic function $g(z)$ with $z \in D \times V$, where $D$ is an open connected
subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $V$ is an open connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Is it true that the zero set of $g(z)$
$$F_2 = \{z \in D \times V | g(z) = 0\}$$
has $(2n+m)$-dimensional Lebesgue measure?

How to prove ( or to modify the proof in [this book](https://books.google.ca/books?id=L0zJmamx5AAC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false), Corollary 10, p.9. to obtain) the above result?

Comment: Naïve question: what is stopping you from taking an ε-neighbourhood of $D × V$?

Comment: Can you explain what a complex analytic function on $D\times V$ means?